# float precision in arduino

Tags: string, float

I am reading a string which i have to convert into a float with a maximum of precision.I didn't want to use toFloat() function since it make a truncation so i made my own code.
My problem is that the final result is also approximated.
I need a precision of 4 digits after the float.I read the documentation about float in the arduino website.They say it should be maximum 7 digits of precision but i don't get it.When i test my code on the value of '23,459' ,all i get is 23,46.
Any suggestions?

```
void setup() { 

 Serial.begin(9600); 


} 
int longu=0;
char data='2';
  String data2="23,459";
  float val=0;
  int posVir=0;
  int t=0;
  float postVir=0;
  float preVir=0;
  int lonPostVir=0;
  int lonPreVir=0;
  float posvir2=0;
  void loop() 
{


   lonPostVir=(data2.substring(posVir+1)).length();
   lonPreVir=(data2.substring(0,posVir)).length();

   longu=data2.length();
   posVir=data2.indexOf(",");
   preVir=(data2.substring(0,posVir)).toFloat();
   postVir=(data2.substring(posVir+1)).toFloat();
   posvir2=postVir*pow(10,-lonPostVir);
   val=preVir+postVir*pow(10,-lonPostVir);

  Serial.println(val);

    }
```

Comment: `Serial.print` only gives two decimal points. (Otherwise it would return `23.4589996337890625` as that is the closest float value that exists.)

Comment: Are you sure about that sir?

Comment: Sure about which of the two statements?

Comment: I confirm that 23.4589996337890625 (i.e. 12299272/2^19) is the float32 nearest to 23.459.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way to get more decimal places to print is this:

```
Serial.println(val,NUMBER_OF_DECMIAL_PLACES);
```

This will print out any number of digits after the decimal place. Regular print without the number of digits specified will default to 2 decimal places. for example, here is some code and the result that gets printed:

```
float val = 23.459;
Serial.println(val);
Serial.println(val, 4);
Serial.println(val, 10);
```

> 23.46
>
> 23.4590
>
> 23.4589996337

You may notice that with 10 decimal places printed you can start to see how much the actual value of 23.459 needs to be approximated to fit within a floating point number. This is similar to how 1/3 can not be represented 100% accurately in a finite number of decimal digits; 459/1000 cannot be represented 100% accurately in a finite number of binary bits, so it is approximated.

Also, note that for non-floating point numbers the optional second argument to `print` and `println` is the base it should be printed in (dec, hex, oct, ...) and has nothing to do with precision.

Answer (score 3):

Just write the amount of numbers you want to get float here Serial.println(val); after the val.
example:
Serial.println(val, 5);
It will give 5 digits after the decimal point